# c# List<t> within a class

Tags: c#, list, class

This a fairly simple question, I have 3 classes (see code below) called projects, sites and wells. The projects class will be a list, but I would like it to contain a list of the sites and then the sites list will contain a list of wells. Not sure if that's allowed. I did a bit of searching and most of the solutions I saw talked more about how to create a list type without knowing what class it was going to be. I know what mine are going to be, so that's not an issue here.

```
Just to give this a visual

    list<t> Projects
            list<t> Sites
                    list<t> Wells


namespace EDMNoCost
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      public class wells
        {
            public string c_wellname { get; set; }
            public string well_id { get; set; }
            public string site_id { get; set; }


            public wells(string c_wellname, string well_id,string site_id)
            {
                this.c_wellname = c_wellname;
                this.well_id = well_id;
                this.site_id = site_id;
            }
        }
        public class sites
        {
            public string c_wellname { get; set; }
            public string site_id { get; set; }
            public string project_id { get; set; }


            public sites(string c_wellname, string site_id, string project_id)
            {
                this.c_wellname = c_wellname;
                this.site_id = site_id;
                this.project_id = project_id;
            }
        }

        public class projects
        {
            public string project_name { get; set; }
            public string project_id { get; set; }
            public string site_id { get; set; }




            public projects(string project_name, string project_id, string site_id)
            {
                this.project_name = project_name;
                this.project_id = project_id;
                this.site_id = site_id;
            }
        }
        public List<projects> projInfo = new List<projects>();
        public List<sites> siteInfo = new List<sites>();
        public List<wells> well_list = new List<wells>();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? You ask whether it is possible to have wells in a site, but your code places them outside the class. They are not part of the containing class

Comment: Just a hint for naming: if the object is a project, name the class Project. Same for Site, Well etc. Also capitalization is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is legal to have that kind of structure and your close, you need to add 1 property for the project and site then you need to change each constructor to initialize the property

when it is done, you can use your code like this;

2 projects

first one have two sites

second one have 1 site and 1 well

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<projects> projInfo = new List<projects>();

            projInfo.Add(new projects("1", "1", "1"));
            projInfo.Add(new projects("2", "2", "2"));

            projInfo[0].siteInfo.Add(new sites("10", "10", "10"));
            projInfo[0].siteInfo.Add(new sites("20", "20", "20"));

            projInfo[1].siteInfo.Add(new sites("30", "30", "30"));

            projInfo[1].siteInfo[0].well_list.Add(new wells("100", "100", "100"));
        }
    }

    public class wells
        {
            public string c_wellname { get; set; }
            public string well_id { get; set; }
            public string site_id { get; set; }

            public wells(string c_wellname, string well_id,string site_id)
            {
                this.c_wellname = c_wellname;
                this.well_id = well_id;
                this.site_id = site_id;
            }
        }
        public class sites
        {
            public string c_wellname { get; set; }
            public string site_id { get; set; }
            public string project_id { get; set; }
            public List<wells> well_list { get; set; } //new property

            public sites(string c_wellname, string site_id, string project_id)
            {
                this.c_wellname = c_wellname;
                this.site_id = site_id;
                this.project_id = project_id;
                well_list = new List<wells>(); //init the property
            }
        }

        public class projects
        {
            public string project_name { get; set; }
            public string project_id { get; set; }
            public string site_id { get; set; }
            public List<sites> siteInfo { get; set; } //new property

            public projects(string project_name, string project_id, string site_id)
            {
                this.project_name = project_name;
                this.project_id = project_id;
                this.site_id = site_id;
                siteInfo = new List<sites>(); //init the property
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is totally legal, just add them as public properties:

```
public class projects
{
    public List<sites> siteInfo { get; set; }
    ...
    public projects (string project_name, string project_id, string site_id)
    {
        this.project_name = project_name;
        this.project_id = project_id;
        this.site_id = site_id;
        this.siteInfo = new List<sites>(); // You can add stuff to the List here if you want, or you can just initialize it.
    }
}
```

You can do the same thing for your other classes as well.